# Bootstrap text input length automatically adjust

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do I set the length of a textbox `input` When I set it like in ASP.net MVC

```
<div class="form-group">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { style = "width:550px", @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
```

the length is set to 550px, put on mobile display the text input doesn't shrink. If I remove the 550px, the text input is 100% long all the way across the screen and it adjusts on mobile screen.

I want the input at a reasonable length at 550px and I want it to shrink on a mobile display automatically.

Is there a way to automatically shrink this input box on mobile display in Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: Which version of Twitter Bootstrap? 2.x or 3.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 3.0, Bootstrap is mobile first. As such, you need to consider the reverse scenario of controlling sizing when you are *not* a mobile screen.

[`form-control`s want to take up `width: 100%` by default](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes), so by setting that `style`, you are overriding the CSS behavior.

Take a look at the example that  I linked to above, and you will see their suggestion of using the `col-*` classes to control the width of your form.  This allows the form to automatically take up more of the page while still working within the Bootstrap scheme.  If you [look at how they do horizontal forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal), then you will see this in full use as I show it below.

From the sounds of it, you want something along the lines of this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I created an equivalent [JSFiddle to play around](http://jsfiddle.net/SYLhd/) if you want to mess with it.  Without `form-horizontal`, the `form`'s controls will collapse to fill any space (e.g., `col-sm-2` and `col-sm-6` leaves 4 available columns in the `sm`all (or above) screen size(s).